# Speeding up matlab file import

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to load a matlab file with the `R.matlab` package. The problem is that it keeps loading indefinitely (e.g. `table <- readMat("~/desktop/hg18_with_miR_20080407.mat")`. I have a genome file from the Broad Institute (`hg18_with_miR_20080407.mat`).

You can find it at:

> http://genepattern.broadinstitute.org/ftp/distribution/genepattern/dev_archive/GISTIC/broad.mit.edu:cancer.software.genepattern.module.analysis/00125/1.1/

I was wondering: has anyone tried the package and have similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

(hopefully helpful, but not really an answer, though there was too much formatting for a comment)

I think you may need to get a friend with matlab access to save the file into a more reasonable format or use python for data processing. It "hangs" for me as well (OS X 10.9, R 3.1.1). The following works in python:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat("hg18_with_miR_20080407.mat")
```

(you can see and work with the `rg` and `cyto' crufty numpy arrays, but they can't be converted to JSON with`json.dumps`and even`jsonpickle.encode`coughs up a lung-full of errors (i.e. you won't be able to use`rPython` to get access to the object which was the original workaround I was looking for), so no serialization to a file either (and, I have to believe the resultant JSON would have been ugly to deal with).

Your options are to:

- get a friend to convert it (as suggested previous)
- make CSV files out of the numpy arrays in python
- use matlab

Comment: thanks! I got a friend's Matlab. Now I am trying to print/search the file.